# Linux compilation configurations

Tags: android, linux

I am doing android-x86 compilation and getting errors. As the problem I am facing is not specific to android, I thot I will get quicker response if I put it with Linux tag.

So,the problem I am facing is as follows:

1. I am trying to change the kernel config file.
2. I am changing it with make menuconfig.
3. When I tried to compile, it puked.
4. The reason is android-x86 does not have support for what I do. But that is not my issue.
5. My issue is: I was under impresseion that menuconfig gives us a default configuration which we change as per our requirements. But I discovered menuconfig is giving me some configuration which is not default. Is there any way to modify specific configuration through menuconfig. So, I want to do something like "make menuconfig **defaultconfig**"

I dont want to modify default config through text file. :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you have to get your "default" config from somewhere else, as it can be very specific to your distro.  For android, I'm not sure where that would be.  On Linux distros, you can usually find them in `/boot/config-*` or `/proc/config.gz`, or somewhere distro-specific.

Copy that to `.config` at the top of your kernel tree, decompressing if necessary, then run `make oldconfig` to answer any new configuration options.  Now your kernel is at the "default" and you can run `make menuconfig` to make your customizations.

Comment: hey thnx :). Able to modify the configuration.